# Detect Maxima Using Persistent Homology

Tags: code-golf, number

Inspired by [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22583391/peak-signal-detection-in-realtime-timeseries-data/46680769#46680769) about peak detection.

### Background

Persistent homology is a fancy term for a fancy math concept, but in this case all we care about is how it can be used for peak detection. In the case of a 1-dimensional array we can describe the algorithm as follows:

We are given an array as input. We begin by sorting it, while maintaining references to the original indices for each value. We also create some kind of data structure to group points together into peaks. We then loop over each point in the sorted array. For each point we have three cases:

- If it is not adjacent to any points in existing groups, a new group is created with a "position" of the point's original index and given a "birth time" equal to that point's value.
- If it is adjacent to one point that is in a group, it is added to said group.
- If it is adjacent to two points in different groups, the younger group is given a "death time" equal to that point's value, and all its points are given to the older group.

At the end, the single group which remains is given a death time of the final value.
Now we have a list of groups, each of which have a position that corresponds to a local maximum, and a persistence which is equal to their "birth time" minus their "death time".

### The challenge

Given a 1-dimensional sequence of inputs which support comparison and subtraction, and an integer \$n \geq 1\$, your task is to output the indices of the \$n\$ most persisent peaks, sorted by their persistence.

Your program does not need to follow the algorithm exactly as I've described it, nor does it need to be as efficient. You only need to support one class of inputs for the sequence (ie. integers, floats, etc.) and any reasonable format for I/O is allowed so long as it is consistent. You may assume that \$n\$ is less than or equal to the number of local maxima.

In the case that two local maxima to be merged have the same "birth time", the behavior for which one persists is undefined, and either is considered valid for this challenge. In the case that two or more maxima have the same persistence, they may appear in any order in the output.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in bytes wins.

### Worked example

Let's look at `[1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1]`. First we'll enumerate and sort `[0:1, 1:2, 2:1, 3:2, 4:3, 5:2, 6:1]` to
`[4:3, 1:2, 3:2, 5:2, 0:1, 2:1, 6:1]` then we iterate over this. I'll show for each iteration what the aforementioned "group" data structure might look like, in this case simply a list of point indices, birth time and death time

```
[[[4], 3, None]]
[[[4], 3, None], [[1], 2, None]]
[[[4, 3], 3, None], [[1], 2, None]]
[[[4, 3, 5], 3, None], [[1], 2, None]]
[[[4, 3, 5], 3, None], [[1, 0], 2, None]]
[[[4, 3, 5, 1, 0, 2], 3, None], [[1, 0], 2, 1]]
[[[4, 3, 5, 1, 0, 2, 6], 3, 1], [[1, 0], 2, 1]]
```

this gives us the a peak at 4 with persistence 3-1=2 and a peak at 1 with persistence 2-1=1 thus our sorted list of peaks is [4,1]

### Test cases

Outputs here are 0-indexed.

```
[1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1]
2
->
[9, 4]

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 7, 6, 5, 6, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 4, 5, 6, 5, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
3
->
[7, 19, 12]

[93, 92, 89, 88, 89, 88, 87, 87, 88, 88, 90, 89, 88, 87, 86, 90, 89, 89, 88, 88, 86, 82, 76, 69, 61, 52, 44, 38, 33, 30, 27, 24, 22, 21, 18, 15, 10, 6, 2, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1, 2, 5, 8, 10, 13, 16]
4
->
[0, 49, 15, 10]
```

More information about persistent homology in general can be found on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_homology) and this [more detailed write-up](https://www.sthu.org/blog/13-perstopology-peakdetection/index.html) by the author of the SO answer.

Comment: This needs a worked example or 2.

Comment: Could you provide the output for the last test case with all peak values? (i.e. with \$n=7\$, I think)

Comment: (It would have been simpler to just output all peaks sorted by their persistence, BTW. The argument \$n\$ seems a bit pointless.)

Comment: _We begin by sorting it_ -> for consistent results, I think it's worth mentioning that this sort must be stable. (Or said otherwise, sorted by decreasing value first and increasing index second.)

Comment: In order, I added a worked example, hopefully it helps. One possible output for \$n=7\$ for the last test case would be `[0, 49, 15, 10, 4, 41, 8]`, but note that swapping the `4` and `41` would be valid too. The point about excluding \$n\$ is fair, though I think changing it now would be a bit of a rug pull. Finally, I'm okay with output not being consistent in order to keep the requirements from being too tight, just like specifying behavior for ties, I think specifying sorting behavior would be too restrictive.

Comment: What's the expected output for [1, 1, 1] for maximum n? It depends on the sorting, if it process the first 1, then last 1, then middle 1, it'll have 2 peaks at indices 0 and 2, with the same persistence of 0. If it process the first 1, middle 1, and last 1, it'll have only 1 peak at index 0 with persistence 0.

Comment: For `[1,1,1]` either `[0,2]` or `[1]` would be valid output, you may assume that \$n\$ would be at most the smallest length possible.

Answer (score 6):

## Python3, 350 bytes:

```py
S=sorted
def f(s,n):
 r,R={},0
 for i,v in S(enumerate(s),key=lambda x:-x[1]):
  R+=1
  if(K:=[r.pop(I)for I in[*r]if i+1in r[I][2]or i-1in r[I][2]]):
   *a,b=S(K,key=lambda x:x[0])
   if a:r[R]=[a[0][0]-v,a[0][1],[]];b[2]+=a[0][2]+[i];R+=1;r[R]=b
   else:b[2]+=[i];r[R]=b
  else:r[R]=[v,i,[i]]
 return[r[i][1]for i in S(r,key=lambda x:-r[x][0])][:n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVDLjoMwDLzzFTkmrbsi4VGg4gOq3tpjlAOoQYu2BRRoRbXab2edsA9aKY6dGXvsuHsM720TJJ2ZplPet2bQZ@@sK1LRHhqWecTAMf/8At8jVWtIDXdSN@REdXO7alMMmvYMPvQjvxTX8lyQMduMkitbSY7rnKOrK3rIcmneuraje2Zl9igiV0bVFanXHAWN3CsplO2wWbxnHbIqoMxP9PDcaJS@YpZGlSIz8qhyWSCGZ3MHF3EFUqldiVLr3CEYyFrt7Gg7V1JaBX3pdTZnWfaPcPisfIcakFO4ET3cTCMNvrCB28q8E/OyCCNHOwxTMmvU1Jm6GWhFJQcigMx38ByHf4gCwZj3UjNnREBiIFsgibvjBTLH4XNm9Bsv1YOleopwiniSoiULv/2xZLbUf@HiBZb@51k8Qb0t@hjxGMeP8B3aCZAPsF@AdQI1BGICOYE5HDmOg3LfDY6o745YbCly/7YZHFV4rCBkbPoG)

Comment: instead of reversing the sorted lists, you can use negative values for the keys, i.e: `key=lambda x:-x[1]`, also you don't need whitespace after the numbers on line 6

Comment: @c-- Thanks, updated.

Comment: Nice answer, removed some conditionals, -71 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVDLboMwELzzFT5VONlU2DzCQ/Sea3Jc@WAEqKgNIIdEiVC@nS6QtiSS117PzI533d66z6Z2w9YMwyE9NaYrcisvSlbaJ6h5bDED@7S/g2OxsjGsgguranawi/p8LIzuCvvE4au4pd/6mOWaXePNFYXi8X6dimSlIUsPNpr3tmntHR8tdmSAK6Oqsq/WAqqNuL/1K4M7hVLdFW8M4gUqQKVUYnCvUs10naNGR9HaXGDKhBoVSUZF6xTpoV7GSPUjRxBWKqEW9Ac@TDIapejOpkZDHJVP48zDmJcJDF5HH64wrtXQmqru7NJGAUwCm3f3Off@EAWSc@ulZlb4wAJgW2DhtAcLZM69Z6X/my/d3aV7RHBEeBhRhItz@4hwjsh54YIFFv3rRjwkvy2dAeEBte/T3Rs7IN6l91yqk@QhCZPESdII4gQ1KpypcUKdacnFL/nT3KNCkIsIFHicDz8 "Python 3.8 (pre-release) – Try It Online")

Comment: @AnttiP Nice golf. I submitted another Python answer (with different algorithm), but I guess it's longer than your further-golfed version now (was shorter than the original 350 bytes).

Comment: Got a sudden urge to golf a few more bytes, -2 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVDLboMwELzzFT5VmGwqbB7hIXrPNTmufDACVNQGkEOiRFG@nS6QtiSS117PzI533V37z7bxos4Mwz47tqYvC6soK1bZR2hgl7ngOIYnFqtaw2o4s7phe7tsTofS6L60jxy@ymv2rQ95odklWV9QKJ7sVplIHQ15trfRvHdtZ2/5aLElA3SMqqtbvRJQr8X97eYY3CqU6q54axDPUAMqpVKDO5VpppsCNbqK1voMUybUqEhzKlplSA/dZIJUP3IEYa1SakF/4MMkt5gp@5Np0BBH5dM48zDmZQKDl9GHK0waNXSmbnq7slEAk8Dm3XvO/T9EgeTceqmZFQGwENgGWDTt4QKZc/9ZGfzmS3dv6R4THBMexRTR4tw8Ipojdl@4cIHF/7oRj8hvQ2dIeEjtB3T3xw6I9@g9j@okeUjCJHGSNII4QY0Kd2qcUHdacvFLwTT3qBDkIkIFPufDDw "Python 3.8 (pre-release) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES10<sup>*</sup>), 215 bytes

*<sup>* ES10 guarantees a stable sort, but the OP has since clarified that this is not a strict requirement.</sup>*

(or [214 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bVDLTsMwEBRXviJHG22i2EnTBOHyIZYPaUlKqjRO-jr1T7hUCH4JCb6GSVwgBSTba8_M7s766aWxD8XpuVSv-13pp-9vuZo1asas0oYH67xlAHItDeXDix2o4mqmEcBv7WbHlorp3JCeGxBzP3dpzElQSrfUGWXPYh6UVb0rNq6uMIDXBVtBt_JVxW9Wd5Jz6o5HpUkbQy2_73TbC9v99pEFQdDhARPU6dD46kDCwOutdTy66sr0nTns1dWiYCE13E33cdUtbLO1dRHUdslKpgV5kjx3Rpf3-BsxnMHT9b-pTjghLyFvSl46nMkIcff4Ujn5ul80if42ycBmoNMMOx3F6XmnbmfhLy4ZYdmPrsdT1JsiJsATTDHBO-6NgI_QL0KeRA0JTIKT0AhwAn5FOPgHGg5Ljv5sMozfKwSqiAQTxfz886eTi58) in ES12, but ATO doesn't seem to be working right now)

Expects `(array)(n)`.

```javascript
a=>n=>(o=[]).map(a=>a[2],a.map((v,i)=>[v,i]).sort(g=([a],[b])=>b-a).map(([v,i])=>([p,q]=o.sort(g).filter(a=>a[1].some(j=>(j-=i)*j<2)),q=q||[,[]],p)?q[p[1].push(...q[1],i),q[0]-=v,1]=[]:o.push([v,[i],i]))).slice(0,n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVBdU4MwEHz3V/CYOAdDwkfBMfWHZPIQK60wlECpfep/x4VUpeoMl9ztbu72aOzFjrtT3Z/Dzr1V015NVm07tWVOacOjo@0ZAKulIbtU7EI1V1uNC/zoTmd2UExbQ/rVgHgNrX/GvAStdE@DUe4m5tG@bs/VyfcVBvCxYg10Tahq/tg8S85pUMP1qkkbQz1/GXQ/K/uP8Z1FUTSggAsadGxCdSFhYPbJeR5jdW3m0Rz@2npXsZg6Pu1cN7q2ilp3YHumBQWSAn8m93n6jRjOYObh36demFGQU7ChoFjOfIX4PL1XZl/53ZDk75ASbAm6KBHF6t7covBRxr@4fIWVP7oZL9BvgzsHnmOLDHU6GwGfYF6CdxI9JDAJTkIjwAn4FfHiH2i8fHL1z7Jl/Vkh0EXk2CjlfPoE)

#### Commented

```javascript
a =>                        // outer function taking a[]
n =>                        // inner function taking n
(o = [])                    // o[] = array of [ value, group, index ] tuples
.map(a =>                   // once o[] is finalized ...
  a[2],                     //   ... keep only the original indices
  a.map((v, i) => [ v, i ]) //   we first turn a[] into an array of
                            //   [ value, index ] pairs
  .sort(g = ([a], [b]) =>   //   and sort them ...
    b - a                   //     ... from highest to lowest value
  )                         //
  .map(([v, i]) =>          //   for each pair [ value, index ]:
    ( [p, q] = o.sort(g)    //     sort o[] by decreasing 'birth time'
      .filter(a =>          //     and keep only the tuples ...
        a[1].some(j =>      //       ... whose groups contain a value
          (j -= i) * j < 2  //       adjacent to the current value
        )                   //
      ),                    //     save at most 2 tuples in [ p, q ]
      q = q || [, []],      //     force a default dummy value for q
      p                     //     test p
    ) ?                     //     if p is defined:
      q[                    //
        p[1].push(          //       append to the group of p:
          ...q[1],          //         the values from the group of q
          i                 //         followed by i
        ),                  //
        q[0] -= v,          //       subtract the 'dead time' from the
        1                   //       'birth time' of q
      ] = []                //       and clear the group of q
    :                       //     else:
      o.push([v, [i], i])   //       create a new tuple
  )                         //   end of inner map()
)                           // end of outer map()
.slice(0, n)                // return only the n first elements
```

Comment: Seems like this was upvoted less than 500ms after I hit the submit button. Either someone is really, really fast or it was a bot.

Comment: I was just staring the spec down, and trying to piece something together out of that, anything's impressive...

Comment: @UnrelatedString TBH, I had to stare at the spec for a while before figuring out what's going on here. I was a little more confused by the 3 links in the question which do provide a bit of context but also a lot of useless information.

Answer (score 4):

## Python, <strike>322</strike> <strike>307</strike> <strike>298</strike> <strike>279</strike> 272 bytes

```python
def P(l,n,*o):
 L=len(l);*u,S=1,*[0]*L,1,sorted
 for i in S(range(L),key=lambda x:-l[x]):*r,d=0,0,1;exec('k,c=i,sum(u[i-(d<0)::d])<2\nwhile~-u[k+1]:r[c]=max(r[c],l[i]-l[k]);k+=d\nd=-1;'*2);o+=((-r[0]or-r[1],i),)*(1>i%~-L*sum(u[i:i+3]));u[i+1]=1
 return[*zip(*S(o))][1][:n]
```

Using different algorithm than the one in the question:

1. Sort descending
2. For each value, if it's a peak (immediate left and right have not been visited) iterate left and iterate right, record max diff until encountering a previously visited value or end of array. Give priority to encountering previously visited value. Store them.
3. Sort and return

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVDLTsMwELz3K3xBeN2NFDttmgfmC3pA6tH4UBoDVlKnMo0oHPj1sm15BKSsdzI7O55k97Z/7kNW7OLx2LhHdsc7DCh6qCZsqTsXeAe1GHClJQqTWrFEiS993Ltmwh77yDzzga14XIcnx5eArXvT3Xr70KzZoUo6c7BQiYiNTjFFWbuD2/DrFjfa48uw5YPxCW9uUqiqxsKNug@vz75zH8lg2qm0VTQbq7frAz8B7Iy35NlaqNupbu5DoxNZXwsFdT/VnCeRIvaRmrToAUFweeuvPpKl@Lqs8tPMAtQEyV7LCYtuP8RgxLvfcbHiPYClbVMFe9xFH/b8jhuJTCG7nNlfPPthLCqAyb@di2KOLEe2QFacz3zEXPDsr3L@jcfu2di9JLokviipilFffFVxqTL9N8tHXPmrO/EF@S2o58TnFH9O77NTAppndF9Ge4o8FHGKZoo0kmaSgsr0HJzY9Pyo0V@an7/7pJDkInOLM4DjJw)

-9 bytes thanks to UnrelatedString
-19 bytes thanks to AnttiP and Kevin
-7 bytes thanks to AnttiP

Comment: [298 with some splat abuse](https://tio.run/##XVDBcoIwEL37Fbl0moRlhgRFoOUfOuMx5mAljhkwOCm0tgd/3S5gKzqTzW7ee3m7yfG73TcuTo/@cinNjrzRGhzwhuUzwjtYFQK4ijSvjaM1AwEfjW9NOSO7xhMLn8Q6sqLGdQfjN63pNZX5LurN4b3ckFMenpTQvRmxO@Kaltinczia8Y/uQDtlcxvEKOEeKthCWUQQgQ2w05XW7FWCeDEns6XPX3tbm3PYqUrnXm01VMVhc6JD@RnWqgqxHVRBuXaj280pt4NTKNbumUv20gQFDT0@rvGYhAbLAOfEloHQhZgRb9rOO8V/7JHyFW0Y0yhTudOXo7eupW9UCSASyLjH9/X8H9EgGZs93BkVCyAJkCWQdNiTCTLW83vl4q@eusdT9wzhDPE0w0gneXmNdIwseuCSCZbddD2eot8Sc4J4guMv8DzvJ0A@xn4x3pPoIRGTyEnUCOQEDiqiYXBEo2HJyS8thnf3CoEuItEwZ@zyCw)

Comment: @UnrelatedString Ooh, interesting! Yea, I haven't used splat abuse in a while I forgot about it. And putting the o into the arguments, nice!

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize we can just add a tuple directly to append using the comma. Thanks for that too

Comment: Now, if only we can remove that u[i+1]=1, we can inline everything.

Comment: Shaved 8 bytes, might return to this later today: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Rc@xbsIwEAbgnae4pcJ2zhKGpTJNn6BDJUbjISVHseLYkeNA6MCrpwFUdbobTt//X3fNpxg2r12appqO8Mk8BhSR6wWIAXelQmFWVngKzHNU2MeUqV7AMSZweAYXYMcoDC2lKtP9pqFr6av2q65g1HI0ynItEjZ4wLpc4QpdMTNDywbjtOVva1RbGunAlpeT83STg2msTuZgsSnbamSP9Sy9aeRsYVPU@/DU/iXtHpJU@7AUa76NRcmYTHP1mOahLDqOXDD17l5u8vmN@Cvhio3lfHvPLdUCEuUhBSN@XMfEjkXO7QwYHez04UIDl6qHHCP4GL4RuqrPBJn63MOJEk2/ "Python 3.8 (pre-release) – Try It Online")

Comment: [I'm playing both sides, so that I always come out on top](https://tio.run/##LY@xbsMgGIT3PAVLFcA/kkmWCoc@gYdKGQmDa3CNjMHCWHU65NVdW@p0t9x3d9Mz9zFc36e0bcZ26BN7CEAjESdUS28D9qSiC9wlB6pKTWvgMMeUrTmhLibkkAvojlMTvi2uCQz2KX0zfpkGrYJ5tWoiaIIBjCyhBFdw4JVdbYvPrZyXES/KMWxuJRHCaHK7PMJP77x9sUUNWiTVajk2Kz4MeOX0zhwY16QaCmke4QAfUMYf4UwvpIqFxJilfWtMu3ANjgChmH@4txer6X@ncMVVE1IdLZKfULJ5SUHRXzdheseREL1nlQh6a@P0RNnOeUa9TRZ1KY4o9xaNzf59inPe/gA "Python 3.8 (pre-release) – Try It Online")

Comment: Ah, nice inlining. So instead of the execution, you control when to output.  Will edit in later when I'm more free. And wow, you make the two Python answers have the same length

Comment: @AnttiP The `\n'*2` can be `;'*2` for -1 byte: [try it online](https://tio.run/##XVDLbuMwDLznK3QpKio0YMmJ40e1X5BDgRwVHbKxuhXsyIEaY9M99NezdNKHW0AU6eFwONbx9fTch6w4xsulcU/skXcYUPRQzdhady7wDmox4EZLFCa1Yo0SX/p4cs2MPfWReeYD2/C4C38cXwO27lV3u8PvZsfOVdKZs4VKRGyx0Smm6OcSZe3Obs/v9/plOPDB@IQ3DylUVWPhQW3D32ffubdkMK2totlbfdid@VhgZ7wlzTaRFup2rpttGIVH0URuw71QUPdzzXkSyWsfKUmLHhAEl7/83VuyFu87Kz/PLEA9btFyxqI7DTEY8c8fudjwHsDSrKmCvRyjDyf@yI1EppDd7ux7vfhELCqA2Y@ZG2OJLEe2QlZc73yC3OrFd@byo56qZ1P1kuCS8KKkKCZ59R7FLcr0Ry@fYOUXb8QL0ltRzgnPyf6SvhejA@pntC@jOUUaijBFPUUcST1JRmV6NU5oej1q8krL63@PDEkqMre4ALj8Bw).

Comment: [Shaved 7 additional bytes](https://tio.run/##XVDLTsMwELz3K3xBeN2NFDttmgfmC3pA6tH4UBoDVlKnMo0oHPj1sm15BKSsdzI7O55k97Z/7kNW7OLx2LhHdsc7DCh6qCZsqTsXeAe1GHClJQqTWrFEiS993Ltmwh77yDzzga14XIcnx5eArXvT3Xr70KzZoUo6c7BQiYiNTjFFWbuD2/DrFjfa48uw5YPxCW9uUqiqxsKNug@vz75zH8lg2qm0VTQbq7frAz8B7Iy35NlaqNupbu5DoxNZXwsFdT/VnCeRIvaRmrToAUFweeuvPpKl@Lqs8tPMAtQEyV7LCYtuP8RgxLvfcbHiPYClbVMFe9xFH/b8jhuJTCG7nNlfPPthLCqAyb@di2KOLEe2QFacz3zEXPDsr3L@jcfu2di9JLokviipilFffFVxqTL9N8tHXPmrO/EF@S2o58TnFH9O77NTAppndF9Ge4o8FHGKZoo0kmaSgsr0HJzY9Pyo0V@an7/7pJDkInOLM4DjJw "Python 3.8 (pre-release) – Try It Online")

Comment: @AnttiP Which parts you changed for that 7 bytes? It's getting harder to keep up now.

Comment: I moved defining `k` to inside the exec call. This allowed to remove the reset of `k` at the end of the while loop (`k,d=i+1,-1`->`d=-1`). Furthermore `k` in this new version is one less than in the previous version (`k->k+1` and `k-1->k`). Since I define `k` inside the exec code, I can't use it outside of that so I reverted `u[k]=1` back to `u[i+1]=1`

Comment: Nice. And the previous `sum(u[i-(d<0)::d])` is nice. I was thinking a bit how to include the condition inside the slice, but didn't realize this one.

Comment: You made this answer shorter by 5 bytes than the other one @AnttiP, haha.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 153 bytes

```python
lambda a,n:sorted(r:=range(N:=len(a)),key=lambda j:max((g:=lambda s,k:g(s,k+s)if k in r and a[k]<=a[j]else min(a[j:k%-N:s]or[0]))(1,j),g(-1,j))-a[j])[:n]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XVBdTsMwDBavPUVekJKRSk3_1kaUE0y7QIhQ0NrSv7RqC2LcBPEyCcGd4DQ47QYdUhLbnz9_tvP22e3Hh1Yf3rPk9uNxzOzo67VWzf1OIUU1H9p-THe450mvdJ7iLU_qVGNFCK3SfXJklrxRzxjn_AQMtOI5hvdqIEWGKlRo1COld0iJSl4nSpQyrYcUNQWIiZJXl_aWD7LthSMJwYyWhObYNpbYhk0E1_I4oMjaHm2M5kvR4VWwwm0HQzmEEsItMze9oy29QwnazGELbqM6nD6pmuIJIcRCXV_ocQ5pZiwhc4vD94UWjCKXovn1zn3_F5GWa9k3logBlJYllpSAopCiNUXR9IYLZPb9c2Zw8pfy3iQPJQxaMNf0iCEZQzYCJIoWdn280Xxj518uXGDxH8_gEeitwYaAh7BEALFv5oC8B_08qHNBwwXMhZwLHAY5BuMyZxofUGc67uKzgml7w2CgwkJp-dNCAPjxqRyWmv_9Bw)

Expects a sequence of positive integers (other positive numbers should work, too).

How?

I'm using the following algorithm which I think is equivalent to OP's:

For each position p find the nearest position with larger value and take the smallest value in between. Do this on the left and the right and keep the larger of the two minima minus the value at p. Sort positions by this quantity.

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 46 bytes

```
ＵＭθ⟦⁻⌈Ｅ⟦⮌…θ⊕κ✂θκ⟧∨⌊…λ⌕Ｅλ›νι¹¦⁰ικ⟧Ｆη⊞υ⌊⁻θυＩＥυ⊟ι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZBBa4QwEIXv@ytyTCAFE11X2aPQ0oNU2qN4CG4Wgxpt1KX99fYZW3Yp5GV03ptvxLpRrh5Ut665GrOh75W90E9OytzYZaK5@jL90qOOtHzXN@0mTbPvutNZM4xb8NXWTvfazvpCW8YYJx@dqfVmtazi5M1RoDzkPtdx8mywaMPi@cVpNWtHLSdmIwjPCfxtoLZi58N1cIQ2jBTL1NCFkz/q/qFYtyB/PhTO2Jlmapo9HcECC4GFua5lmYacpJKTJIWSh3r6VbIrDf558UMvvee2fgLeCTVGPxacHPEeRZyE8EPsCzEnwZDoSXgSGQFPHCF4GEU38Ef6I/wNO9kTAhQR43dG1fp0634A) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Port of @Albert.Lang's Python answer, because it's the only post here I could understand.

```
ＵＭθ⟦⁻⌈Ｅ⟦⮌…θ⊕κ✂θκ⟧∨⌊…λ⌕Ｅλ›νι¹¦⁰ικ⟧
```

For each element of the input array, get the reversed prefix and suffix, truncate each at the first element greater than the current element, then take the minimum, or zero if the list is empty, subtract the current element from the larger of the two, and pair it with the current index.

```
Ｆη⊞υ⌊⁻θυ
```

Get the persistence and index of the `n` most persistent peaks.

```
ＩＥυ⊟ι
```

Output the indices.

Answer (score 0):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), <del>516</del> 511 bytes

Port of [@Ajax1234's Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/262270/110802) in Scala.

Saved many bytes thanks to the comment of [@Aiden Chow](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/96039/aiden-chow)

---

Golfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVDLjpswFN3nK7y0hbECJAQmJVIrdRGl00W66KIaRSYxHTdgKHbRpJl8e3oNYQbajuT78LnnPvWe5/wqi6qsDdL2w/Zlnou9kaVixS/D01xMJmX6AyB0z6VC4skIddDofVWh8/UgMpRhffdF/Py2VuaBqjswJDk3PEd1cqvA7nllwxRbZaXnkwdMlg2v0TaZLrOyxrihkrxzNfstq6/SPK7VQTwxDfN9OOFGJivkNpLtPELaFpukZkdx0iyTuRE1XicrUITtAlhEGRhYY@l45Pn5X9iFIqzgVZvEalGUjbCk78IQZkoYse@7sw2XMsMbpkr1sajMqW2POU1JAqhU0tANy7k2ZLl1Es@S@YBcOwneuivAHgU/QDm3ob3v088yJ7e8npgCh6Y2CCpwnJ4MLgyGJSHkInItzm8lvLA62qg43Ji@xpe3E45WPtpL1/hI7OrtlaQ9rYS/D9fhR4EVuVwRqmqpTK5whj9JbbBHkU9Rp4OxP3tBCBhCJm8kd9Q5RSFFC4qiVocDpPNnY@a890dtgv@1iSEeAyGKQaKBXdwk6iSe/hULB1j8yrN4BPUWYEPAQ9hjDv@ZHQXiAfQLIM@HGj5gPsR84HgQ82Bib9puAOi0ff7gbvP2AJbhQRUvhJ1msNPl@gc)

```scala
def f(s:Seq[Int],n:Int)={val r=mutable.Map[Int,(Int,Int,Seq[Int])]();var R=0;for((v,i)<-s.zipWithIndex.sortBy(vi=> -vi._1)){val K=r.keys.filter(I=>r(I)._3.contains(i+1)||r(I)._3.contains(i-1)).map(I=>r.remove(I).get).toSeq.sortBy(_._1);if(K.nonEmpty){val(a,b)=(K.init,K.last);R+=1;if(a.nonEmpty){r+=(R->(a.head._1-v,a.head._2,Nil));R+=1;r+=(R->(b._1,b._2,b._3++a.head._3++Seq(i)))}else{r+=(R->(b._1,b._2,b._3++Seq(i)))}}else{R+=1;r+=(R->(v,i,Seq(i)))}};r.keys.toSeq.sortBy(k=> -r(k)._1).map(i=>r(i)._2).take(n)}
```

Ungolfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVJNj9owEL3zK@Zoi2CR8L0qK7VSD4huD/TQQ7VCBpyuu8FJExctZfnt9NkhKUGR4o@ZefP8ZibFVibyovdZmlsqnCG2aZKordWpEfs/Vm4S1emkm19w0ZPUhtSbVWZX0Mcso9Nlp2KKWfHwTf3@sTD2OTAPOPj81CE6yIRymtOVRjzJzGECYn73W5XHnxn3KTmtkNLHPU5zYuwQkOb0oUesEH919l3bl4XZqTdRQPKnI51oKwtFV9z8kXqHM@fk3i8VLEGXi1d1LLyLSMQ6sSpnC4fGwcV6gKqNRXUF09SlkNP7e1uohxCvaPYyu3KIXO3Tg3L4n8rWAJuiusoo5bK1WIclQMfElsKk5vM@s8dKcamZyYA2qMYhtNHo01IksqipV9SdU3g1HJFsISI0HzC2ot6jQ7woucPrKAK9qswooK86qYu6o25SbJANXT4J@4C63ZrHGyiXaV6TnUklGE2rnna2e4JOC01D4K089wcETQpH4FY5/3Ig1STg8b9L7m7cjcVPVJd/hYYn4sLKV8UM75wvRFmujU0Mi9kXXVgG8VBe7oPmfVh7OA6vpTW5hI4CGgc0CWjq9/GNp7wPm8hRdW88M2h7Zob4DIDpDGt6c06ua1quWf8uNr7xzf7jnH8KvgnOMfxj1DGCPXRSEB/gvQHyInBE8EWIRcCEiIVQHPZ9BfD2/Rfd9G3kG@AQIVjCMWoactf5fw)

```scala
def f(s:Seq[Int],n:Int)={
  val r = mutable.Map[Int, (Int, Int, Seq[Int])]()
  var R = 0
  for ((v, i) <- (s.zipWithIndex.sortBy { case (v, i) => -v})) {
    val K = r.keys
      .filter(I => r(I)._3.contains(i + 1) || r(I)._3.contains(i - 1))
      .map(I => r.remove(I).get)
      .toSeq
      .sortBy(_._1)
    if (K.nonEmpty) {
      val (a, b) = (K.init, K.last)
      R += 1
      if (a.nonEmpty) {
        r += (R -> (a.head._1 - v, a.head._2, Nil))
        R += 1
        r += (R -> (b._1, b._2, b._3 ++ a.head._3 ++ Seq(i)))
      } else {
        r += (R ->  (b._1, b._2, b._3 ++ Seq(i)))
      }
    } else {
      R += 1
      r += (R -> (v, i, Seq(i)))
    }
  }
  r.keys.toSeq.sortBy(key => -r(key)._1).map(i => r(i)._2).take(n)
}
```

Comment: Is this even fully golfed? I see a lot of whitespace here; I doubt that they are all required for the code to run correctly.

Comment: @Aiden Chow Thanks. I have updated.

Comment: That looks a lot better, but you should golf your code before posting it next time. Also in `vi => -vi._1` the space after `vi` can be removed, so `vi=> -vi._1`.

Comment: There's also one part that has `key=> -r(key)._1`, I think that could just be `k=> -r(k)._1`.